# Error analysis in measuring wavelength using diffraction grating

Tags: experimental-physics, diffraction, error-analysis

If $\alpha_m$ are the diffraction angles where the diffracted wave has maxima, then the wavelength is given by the following
$$d\sin{\alpha_m} = m\lambda.$$
In order to find $\lambda$, I've run a series of experiments, measuring different values of $\alpha_m$. Now that I have my data I realized that I don't know how to proceed further. I think I could calculate $\lambda$ from the equation above using linear regression (finding $m$ in $y=mx+b$ with $m=\lambda$ and $y=d\sin{\alpha_m}$). **But I'm not sure how to go about doing the error analysis here**. Excel's LINEST is going to give some approximation error, but I have to take the inaccuracy of measuring $\alpha_m$ and $d$ into account as well.

Here's the data I collected along with the plot ($d=7.35$

[image: diffraction]

Comment: Can you please add data and/or a plot to your question? There is at least a theoretical and a data driven approach towards answers.

Comment: @MS-SPO I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thansk. See my (first) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data driven approach I deliberately reserve a second answer: it's a different approach, and it's lengthy, too.

First let's have a look and slightly rearrange your data:

- $d \cdot \sin(\alpha_m) = \lambda \cdot m$ is what you know
- $y = \beta \cdot M$, where: $y$ is dependent, $M (=m)$ is the variable, slope $\beta$ relates directly to $\lambda$ you are interested in.

Now the calculations:

- rearranged data at top left
- ANOVA (ANalysis Of VAriances) to the right, which decomposes all available sum_of_squares, residual == error estimate
- yM-plot lower left ("magnified" to show error bars $\pm \sigma_e$ , see below)

[image: data]

I'll now denote the non-obvious terms:

- $r = \sum M_i^2$
- $T = \sum y_i$ (not needed)
- $L = \sum y_i \cdot M_i$
- ~ ~ ~
- $S_t = \sum y_i^2$ total variation
- $S_{\beta} = \frac{L^2}{r}$ variation of the slope
- $S_e = S_t -S_{\beta} $ error variation (here for 4 degrees of freedom (DOF))
- $V_e = \frac{S_e}{f_e}$ error variance (i.e. mean variation per DOF); $\sigma_e = \sqrt(V_e)$
- ~ ~ ~
- $S_{\beta}* = S_{\beta} - V_e$  purified variation of the slope (it's an approximation)
- $\beta^2 = \frac{S_{\beta}*}{r} $ take the sqrt to obtain $\lambda$

So your result is $\lambda = 3.12 \pm 0.16$ in whatever units you measured $d$, or about $\pm 5$ % as a relative error.

$V_e$ contains or pools ALL errors of your experiments. These include the ones I calculated in my other answer PLUS any other uncontrolled variation you might have had. These may contain e.g.:

- inaccurate readings of $d$ or $\alpha_m$
- coinciding orders, i.e. hard to separate
- fatigue, hurry, impatience
- mechanical or procedural issues
- variation in temperature, pressure etc.
- vibrating floors
- and so on and so on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Here's the classical approach. For the data driven one I need to review your data, which look a bit strange at first glance (though you might be right to view it this way).

3 Steps:

- calculate the partials
- obtain relative errors
- sum them up as squares.

You want to know the accuracy of $\lambda$, so here we go:

- $\lambda = \frac{d}{m} \sin(\alpha_m)$
- you can have errors in $d, m$ and $\alpha_m$
- partials: $\partial \lambda = \frac{\partial d}{m}\sin(\alpha_m) - \partial m \cdot \frac{d}{m^2}\sin(\alpha_m) + \partial \alpha_m \cdot \frac{d}{m} \cos(\alpha_m) $
- rewritten: $\partial \lambda = \frac{\partial d}{d}\lambda - \frac{{\partial m }}{m}\lambda + \partial \alpha_m \cdot \frac{\lambda}{\tan(\alpha_m)}  $
- rewritten: $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\lambda} = \frac{\partial d}{d} - \frac{{\partial m }}{m} +   \frac{\partial \alpha_m}{\tan(\alpha_m)}  $
- rewritten as relative errors: $\frac{\Delta\lambda}{\lambda} = \frac{\Delta d}{d} - \frac{{\Delta m }}{m} +   \frac{\Delta \alpha_m}{\tan(\alpha_m)}  $
- rewritten as sumsquares: $\frac{\Delta\lambda}{\lambda}^2 = \frac{\Delta d}{d}^2 + \frac{{\Delta m }}{m}^2  +   \frac{\Delta \alpha_m}{\tan(\alpha_m)}^2  $

So this is simple error propagation. All you need to do is to quantify (i.e. estimate) all 3 relative errors. $\frac{{\Delta m }}{m}$ may or may not be zero, depending on your experiment, reviewing your notes. If it turns out you made a mistake in some data point, i.e. mixed the order, calculate and draw a dedicated error bar for this data point.